# Constructing a Hamiltonian $S^1$-action on a neighborhood of a symplectic divisor

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $M^{2n}$ be a symplectic manifold and let $M^{2n-2}$ be a symplectic submanifold. How to construct a non-trivial Hamiltonian $S^1$-action on $M^{2n-2}$ on a small neighborhood of $M^{2n-2}$, that would fix $M^{2n-2}$? 
(I think I saw a reference to this statement in some book, but can not find it now.)

Comment: A reference is Seidel's biased view of symplectic cohomology.

Comment: Thanks YHBKJ, though there is no proof there "In the simplest case of a smooth D = K, this is quite elementary (it follows from the
tubular neighbourhood theorem for symplectic submanifolds)."

Answer (score 2):

I  don't have any reference, but I think that the idea is as follows:
There is a tubular neighborhood theorem according to which a neighborhood of $M^{2n-2}$ is isomorphic to symplectic disc bundle over $M^{2n-2}$.
Take a complex structure J compatible with the symplectic form in each fiber. This gives you a metric $\omega(\cdot, J\cdot)$ on each fiber with associated norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Now take the Hamiltonian function $H(x,y)=\pi\|y\|^2$, where $x$ is the variable in $M^{2n-2}$ and $y$ is the fiber variable. It generates a rotation flow in each fiber, and at time 1, it is back to identity.

EDIT: this answer does not work. See Tim Perutz's comments below for how to fill the gap.

Comment: Could you please say what you mean by "symplectic disc bundle"? Do you  take $J$ for which the bundle is almost complex?

Comment: Let me be more precise on the tubular neighborhood theorem: the bundle involved is the bundle whose fiber at $x\in M^{2n-2}$ is the symplectic orthogonal to $TM^{2n-2}$. This is proved in the book by McDuff and Salamon

Comment: This bundle is symplectic in the sense that there is a (natural) symplectic form on each fiber, which smoothly depends on the base point. Since the base is also a symplectic manifold, the total space carry a symplectic structure as well.

Comment: $J$ turns this bundle into a complex bundle (actually there is no need for the word "almost" here, and I removed it from my initial answer) Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately there is a problem. In your defintion the total space of a symplectic bundle does not necessarily have a structure of symplectic manifold. In general, I don't believe that answer is correct in the present form. Indeed, consider, the symplectic manifold $S^2\times S^2$  with a standard product symplectic form $\omega$. Now add to this form a small generic form $\omega_t$ (so that $\omega+\omega_t$ is still symplectic). I claim, that there is no Hamiltonian $S^1$ symmetry of $\omega+\omega_t$ preserving vertical fibration - because of symplectic  curvature of this fibration

Comment: @aglearner You are correct to notice the distinction between a symplectic vector bundle and a symplectic form on its total space. But the gap can be filled by the following construction of (IIRC) Kostant. Let $p: L\to M$ be a hermitian line bundle over the symplectic manifold $(M,\omega_M)$. Let $\alpha$ be a connection 1-form on the principal $U(1)$-bundle of unit vectors in $L$. Let $\mu$ be the moment map for the rotation action of $U(1)$ on $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: ...Then the form $d\langle \alpha, \mu \rangle + \omega_{\mathbb{C}}$ on $P\times \mathbb{C}$ descends to $P\times_{U(1)} \mathbb{C} = L$, and after adding $p^*\omega_M$ one gets a symplectic form near the zero-section of $L$ which restricts to $\omega_M$ on the zero-section and which has a hamiltonian $U(1)$ action.

Comment: Tim, thanks for these comments! They fill the gap indeed. May I ask you, maybe you saw the statement in my question proven in some book? (I wonder if one can not construct this Hamiltonian $S^1$-action without using Weinstein neighbourhood theorem..)

Comment: I don't know such a reference. My expectation would be that typical proofs will either apply the neighborhood theorem, or use its standard method of proof (Moser's argument). My reference to Kostant was wrong, it should have been to Sternberg, PNAS vol. 74, 1977.

Comment: Yes, I clearly missed something here. Thanks for filling the gap Tim.